# TFS: Mapping to same folder for different users

Tags: version-control, tfs

Our team works on virtual machines. These machines have the same name and a common location(d:\Build) that everyone works against. How can we map different people's workspaces to work against the same location in TFS? "User 2" gets the path "d:\Build" is already mapped in workspace ;\ error when he tries to map to the same location. Several forums entries point to using a "junction point" but these entries do not seem to be very clear.

Comment: How can your team use the sam name for different machines in one domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to the [junction utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) (it's symbolic links for windows users). The way I understand your setup, you will need to create unique folders for each one of your users, and then create a junction to "D:\Build".

Comment: We did not use the junction utility mentioned above. We instead mapped the "d:\Build" folder on a VM in TFS source control to a logical drive on your VM. We used a software like "Visual Subst"to do the same.